# Global option to turn on/off section numbering

Tags: sectioning, options

Suppose I want to change from numbering my \sections, \subsections, and so on to not numbering them.

As far as I know, the only way is to manually change (e.g.) \section{Foo} to \section*{Foo} and so on, all through the document... one by one.

That seems at odds with the LaTeX philosophy.  It is also a very manual and tedious process, especially when one has a master document and sub-files.  I know there are tricks within editors and the command line to globally replace text with replacement text... but a cleaner solution would be a LaTeX option.

In other words:  Is there a global LaTeX option one can set to swap from numbered to unnumbered sectioning (and vice verse)?

P.

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` will only number chapters (if existent).

Comment: You could redefine each sectioning command to the starred version like: `\let\section\section*`